# python, zenoss old dictionary new dictionary

Tags: python, dictionary, zenoss

I have a dictionary with the following structure as:

```
Data2 = {
'1.1.1': {'unitReturnAirTemperature': 224, 'unitAirTemperature': 224, 'unitHumidity': 430, 'unitReturnAirHumidity': 431}, 
'1.1': {'unitName': 'Unit-01'}, 
'1.2': {'unitName': 'Unit-02'}, 
'1.2.1': {'unitReturnAirTemperature': 215, 'unitAirTemperature': 224, 'unitHumidity': 431, 'unitReturnAirHumidity': 399}
}
```

And I would like to get the following:

```
Data3 = {
'1.1.1': {'unitReturnAirTemperature': 224, 'unitAirTemperature': 224, 'unitHumidity': 430, 'unitReturnAirHumidity': 431, 'unitName': 'Unit-01'}, 
'1.2.1': {'unitReturnAirTemperature': 215, 'unitAirTemperature': 224, 'unitHumidity': 431, 'unitReturnAirHumidity': 399, 'unitName': 'Unit-02'}
}
```

The new dictionary (`Data3`) should be based on the data from `Data2` dictionary.

Comment: So is the logic here that `1.1.1`'s dictionary is grouped with `1.1`'s dictionary, and `1.2.1`'s dictionary is grouped with `1.2`'s dictionary?

Comment: So you want to keep the *newest* version for every subversion?

Comment: Yeap, I do want to grouped data according the logic: 1.1.1's dictionary is grouped with 1.1's dictionary, and 1.2.1's dictionary is grouped with 1.2's.

Comment: So you want to keep the newest version for every subversion? - Sorry could you clarify your question.